# I want to create a Makefile in every child directory and list all the directory names in that make file in Unix

Tags: makefile

I want to create a Makefile in every child directory and list all the directory names in that make file:
For example we have a dir structure like:

```
root    

root/angela1    

root/angela2    

root/angela1/testangela1    

root/angela2/testangela2    

root/angela2/testangela2
```

Now I want to run a script or command which will create a Makefile with some content along with the directory names of the working dir.. The make files should be created something in this way

```
root -----> script/command should create makefile with some text defined and dir name angela1 and angela2    

root/angela1-----> script/command should create makefile with some text defined and dir name testangela1    

root/angela2-----> script/command should create makefile with some text defined and dir name testangela2 and testangela3    

root/angela1/testangela1-->No Makefiles created as no child dir avalil    

root/angela2/testangela2-->No Makefiles created as no child dir avalil    

root/angela2/testangela3-->No Makefiles created as no child dir avalil
```

Note: Also if a Makefile is present the script/command should create/modify the one present
Could anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried? If we show you how to create a list of subdirectories (e.g. `angela1 angela2`), can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks for your response..I have already a dir structure..
So I use the command 

"find ./ -type d -exec touch {}/Makefile1 \;"


OR

"find . -maxdepth 5  -type d | xargs -I currentDir -t touch  currentDir/Makefile"


TO create empty Makefiles and it works too..

But now I want to add the directory names in the path that respective makefile is as written in the example by appending all the Makefiles created with the above command..

Comment: I am waiting for some one to help.. please..

Comment: Your language is very difficult to read, and the problem itself is tricky, but I for one am working on a `find` approach.